# How do I embed a pygame window into a website?

Tags: python, pygame, embed

I've already searched **a lot** but I can't find a solution... So: I made a game in python and I want to publish it on a site. But there's a problem because I don't know how to do I think it's also because I don't want the code on my website but I want **only the game to show up** on my site. So can someone please help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Python doesn't run on the browser. You can give people your files to run, you cannot make it playable on the website

Comment: @h4z3 Is there any other way I can publish my game?

Comment: I wanted to say that itch.io is for indie games, but in the meantime I actually searched if itch.io allows just python files... and found someone actually finding and suggesting online ide thingy that can run pygame. https://trinket.io/features/python3 https://trinket.io/features/pygame It also explains how it "runs" python in browser: `Did you know? We run a special virtual machine to display the images and produce the sounds you here, then stream them to your browser.`  [found it via https://itch.io/jam/the-text-based-adventure-game-jam/topic/527620/can-i-just-upload-a-python-file]